# pre-ordered and empty morphism

Tags: category-theory

In Rotman An introduction to algebraic topology. If $X$ has a transitive and reflexive relation $\le$. Prove that the following construction gives a category $\mathscr C$. Define $Obj(\mathscr C)=X$, if $x,y$ $\in$ $X$ and $x\not\le y$, define $Hom(x,y)= \varnothing$, otherwise, define $Hom(x,y)$ to be a set with exactly one element, denoted by $i^{x}_{y}$; if $x\le$ $y\le$ $z$, define the compostion by $i^{y}_{z}$ $i^{x}_{y}$=$i^{x}_{z}$.

All my problem is empty set.
Since by definition, the composition $Hom(x,y)$ $\times$ $Hom(y,k)$ $\to$ $Hom(y,k)$, so if $x\not\le y$, $x\not\le z$ ,$y\le z$, we have the compostion ( $\star$  ,$i^{y}_{z}$) $\to$ $(i^{y}_{z}\circ \star )$
,where $\star$ means element in empty set. In this step although this seems weird, I can accept. However, when I do the associate of the compostion, I get some trouble.

For  the case $Hom(z,k)$  $\times$  $Hom(y,z)$  $\times$ $Hom(x,y)$ $\to$ $Hom(x,k)$ where $x\not\le y$,$y\not\le z$,$z\not\le k$

$( \star,(\star ,\star))$={$\star\circ\star$     if $x\not\le z$; $\star\circ$ $i^{x}_{z}$ if $x\le z$}= {$\star$ ,if $x\not\le k$; $i^{x}_{k}$ if $x\le k$ } , on the other hand, since we change the compostion order, we need to consider the relation between y and k, which is "NOT" the case before, so I have no idea to deal with the empty case for the defintion, Does there exist some conventions about the homomorphism be empty set and how to do the compostion about the element in empty set.

From the website, I know that it is " boring" when the hom-set is empty, but I do this just for the completeness.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The hom sets you're referencing in the definition of composition are wrong. Also how can $\star$ be an element of the empty set? Are you sure you're reading the definitions in the book properly?

Comment: what wrong with the hom set? also , I just use star to represent some idea , I know that empty set has no element. Moreover, why every defintion not exclud this case (i.e hom-set be empty set, how to well define d the compostion?)

Comment: or you can replace star as blank space "   " if you want, then how to define the compostion?

Answer (score 1):

To show that this is a category you would need to show (for all $x,y,z,w \in \text{Ob(C)}$):

1. For each $g \in \text{Hom(x,y)}$ and $f \in \text{Hom(y,z)}$, there exist an element $f \circ g \in \text{Hom(x,z)}$
2. There exists $\text{id}_x \in \text{Hom(x,x)}$ such that for any $f \in \text{Hom(x,y)}$ we have $f \circ \text{id}_x = f$ and for any $f \in \text{Hom(y,x)}$ we have $\text{id}_x \circ f = f$
3. For any $h \in \text{Hom(x,y)}$, $g \in \text{Hom(y,z)}$ and $f \in \text{Hom(z,w)}$, it holds that $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$.

First we will show (1):

Let $g \in \text{Hom(x,y)}$ and $f \in \text{Hom(y,z)}$. By the definition of  $C$, we have $x \le y$ and $y \le z$. By transitivity of $\le$, we know $x \le z$. Thus there exists an element $h \in Hom(x,z)$. Thus we can define $f \circ g := h$.

Notice that we don't need to define anything in the case that $\text{Hom(x,y)} = \varnothing$ or $\text{Hom(y,z)} = \varnothing$. If you want to be really strict about the definition of the composition, you need to remember that it is a collection of mappings of the form

$$
\text{Hom(x,y)} \times \text{Hom(y,z)} \rightarrow \text{Hom(x,z)}
$$

for each $x,y,z$ in $\text{Ob}(C)$. If the set $\text{Hom(x,y)} \times \text{Hom(y,z)}$ is empty, then you can just take the empty function. If $\text{Hom(x,z)}$ is empty, then this implies that $\text{Hom(x,y)} \times \text{Hom(y,z)}$ is also empty, in which case you can also take the empty function. Now to show (3):

Assume we have some $h \in \text{Hom(x,y)}$, $g \in \text{Hom(y,z)}$ and $f \in \text{Hom(z,w)}$. Thus by (1), we have $g \circ h \in \text{Hom(x,z)}$ and $f \circ g \in \text{Hom(y,w)}$. Repeating the argument we have $(f \circ g) \circ h \in \text{Hom(x,w)}$ and $f \circ (g \circ h) \in \text{Hom(x,w)}$. Since $\text{Hom(x,w)}$ contains at most a single element, it follows that $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$.

You can try showing (2) as an exercise.